# Who were the models that portrayed the “Figure In Black” and the “War Pig” on the covers of the first 2 Black Sabbath albums?

Tags: artwork, black-sabbath

Does anyone know the names of the models on the covers of the first 2 Black Sabbath Albums? The “Figure In Black” (On the cover of “Black Sabbath”) May have been named Louise, With a first name in mind, are there any possible ways to find out who this Louise is? I would also like to find the identity of the model who portrayed the “War Pig on the cover art of the “paranoid” album, does anyone also know WHERE the paranoid cover picture was taken? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

References in the wikipedia article about the album [Black Sabbath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Sabbath_(album))  lead to [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20180511020659/http://www.feelnumb.com/2011/09/13/black-sabbath-debut-album-cover-photo-location/) about the phoshoot location.

From that page:

> "Not much is known about the eerie woman used in the photo other then
>   she was a model/actress hired for the day and her name was Louise."

From [another page](https://loudwire.com/cover-stories-black-sabbath-self-titled-debut/) some more info

> Johnny Morgan and Ben Wardle write:
>
> The ghostly figure dressed in black robes standing there is an actress
>   hired for the shoot by Vertigo Records' in-house designer "Keef"
>   Macmillan....She may not represent death but must have done a good job
>   of unsettling the more pharmaceutically affected Sabbath fans. Look
>   closely and -- supposedly -- she's holding a black cat.
>
> Rumors abounded in the pre-internet days: She was a real witch, "she"
>   is really Ozzy in drag, the photo was taken at an actual "black
>   sabbath," and perhaps the best one: There was no woman at the photo
>   shoot -- the ghostly figure only appeared when the film was developed.
>   As fun as the legends are, that's all they are: stories. She was
>   really there, really paid for her day's work, and might have been
>   named Louise.
>
> Another favorite story was that the band had no idea who the
>   apparition was, which happens to be true, though Sabbath may have
>   encountered "Louise" years later. Geezer Butler told author Martin
>   Popoff for his book, Fade to Black: "We had a gig in, I believe,
>   Lincolnshire in England, and this girl came up to us, dressed just
>   like the cover. And she was allegedly that person. Whether it's true
>   or not, there's no way of proving it."

for the War Pig on ["Paranoid"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paranoid_(album)) :   the photographer was Keith MacMillan (aka Marcus Keef). All the material out there about the album and its artwork only seems to mention the change in title of the album - it was originally to be called "War Pigs".

It's likely the bearded guy with the sword and the pink tights is an unknown actor/model hired for the photoshoot : an idea floated on this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/blacksabbath/comments/9xrq55/who_is_the_guy_on_the_cover_of_the_paranoid/)